# Disallow link shorteners on Careers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, hyperlinks

Seeing as we disallow/discourage link shorteners in Stack Exchange questions and answers, should we not also do the same for companies posting openings in Careers?

I bumped into this today on a company profile:

[image]

The offending link is at the bottom right of the "hero banner" image on this un-named company page (the pages that reside at https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/companyname)

If any "Careers" development staff want to contact me directly to find out who's page this is then my contact details are in my profile.

Comment: How is this a "feature-request"?

Comment: @TrevorClarke:  It's not a bug since there's no aberrant behavior with anything about the link.  It's a feature request since the desire is to *remove* certain behaviors.

Comment: @Makoto - and still, with shorteners banned across SE, this is a security-related bug.

Comment: Fair point. However it is a problem that it is there and needs to be removed. Not added. However I guess it doesn't matter much. Good find either way! @Makoto

Comment: Funny thing is that company page link you posted goes to a test company page...

Comment: @JonH, That's one more bug for your long list of Careers bug tracking ;)

Comment: i hate link shorteners, they should be banned from the internet. they're a twitter solution to a twitter problem.

Comment: @Zanon - I've reduced tracking bugs as much as I used to file them.  Too many "status-by-design" crap I don't want to deal with.

Comment: @rupps They're sometimes useful for IRC and text messaging as well.

Comment: They might be useful, but I won't click them. If I think it is an interesting add, I simply Google the company to find their Careers section.

Comment: This may be a company that wants to track where their candidates found the job, and are too lazy to set up a custom URL on their site like "companyname.com/stackoverflowjobs" or something. Instead, they farm that work off on the shortening service, which I believe will tell you the referrers for clicks...

Comment: If the world was perfect, link shorteners would be useful. But unfortunately many times they are used for more harm than good, blindly referring you somewhere